# jQuery Accordion stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-accordion

after a mess with my FTP client, my Wordpress' header.php got deleted, so I need to re-code it and a former working jQuery script stopped working, but I can't find the problem.

It is an accordion script which can have multiple sections open at the same time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".post-list").addClass("ui-accordion ui-accordion-icons ui-widget ui-helper-reset")
            .find("h3.entry-title")
            .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom")
            .hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover"); })
            .click(function() {
              $(this)
                .toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom")
                .next().toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active").slideToggle();
              return false;
        })
        .next()
        .addClass("ui-accordion-content  ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom")
        .hide();

        var d= 0;
        $('.post').each(function() {
            $(this).delay(d).fadeIn(300);
            d += 100;
        });
});

</script>
```

It's supposed to find the H3's, add classes and hide the following div's. I put it in the head-area of my header.php, all necessary libraries get loaded, but somehow the script doesn't seem to work at all.

Can anyone find a mistake or suggest what might be wrong with the script's implementation?

Note: I tried the exact same script on a local dummy website and it works.

Thanks!

Comment: probably missing the jquery css file

Comment: Have you checked the console, are you getting any error?

Comment: It says "can't find variable: $"

Comment: All libraries are loaded at the bottom of the body-tag, but I think that's how wordpress always loads them

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting "can't find variable: $" error on console, that means jQuery is not loaded or conflicts any other libraries.

First check whether `window.$` or `window.jQuery` exist on console.

And try to use `jQuery` instead `$`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".post-list").addClass("ui-accordion ui-accordion-icons ui-widget ui-helper-reset")
            .find("h3.entry-title")
            .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom")
            .hover(function() { jQuery(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover"); })
            .click(function() {
              jQuery(this)
                .toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom")
                .next().toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active").slideToggle();
              return false;
        })
        .next()
        .addClass("ui-accordion-content  ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom")
        .hide();

        var d= 0;
        jQuery('.post').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).delay(d).fadeIn(300);
            d += 100;
        });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the part with `window.$` etc. and I tried the code but still it didn't work. It works if I put the original code in a seperate .js-file and enqueue it in functions.php with `array('jquery')` . But still I can't figure out why it worked before?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12225872/603127) It might work. As you said your script code works before jQuery loaded. And It seems there isn't any way to make a non-file js code work after jQuery loaded except [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12225872/603127)

Comment: I guess I'll stick to the method with a seperate JS-File, seems the safest way. But thanks for the help and wind.onload explanation!